# how to remove stay on click option in bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove stay on click in bootstrap dropdown menu. 
Right now when i mouse hover dropdown is showing and when i click also dropdown menu is showing. I want to remove click and show event. Need to show the dropdown menu only on hover and not on click.

```
<li class="list-inline-item dropdown">
                    <a id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">                 
                          <li class="dropdown-item">
                              <a href="">Menu1</a>
                          </li> 
                          <li class="dropdown-item">
                              <a href="">Menu2</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown-item">
                              <a href="">Menu3</a>
                          </li>                          

                        </ul>
                  </li>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `navbar` code

Comment: i have added the code pls check @FareedKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `jquery` and `css` you can make your `navbar` dropdown workable only on `hover` but not get active on `click`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown, .btn-group").hover(function() {
    var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
    if (dropdownMenu.is(":visible")) {
      dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu,
  .btn-group:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
  .navbar .dropdown-toggle,
  .nav-tabs .dropdown-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<!--Navbar with dropdown menu-->
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="list-inline-item dropdown">
          <a id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
              <a href="">Menu1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
              <a href="">Menu2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item">
              <a href="">Menu3</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```